# DC - Can geoChoroplethChart be combined with bubbleOverlay?

Tags: dc.js, choropleth

This example (http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/crime/index.html) looks great but the path elements and SVG for the map of Canada have been defined manually. I'd like to draw a world map with geoChoroplethChart and then add a bubbleOverlay.

I've tried them separately and recently tried a compositeChart approach:

```
  compositeChart.width(1440)
                .height(500)
                .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 60})
                .compose([
                    dc.geoChoroplethChart("#us-chart")
                            .dimension(countries)
                            .projection(projection)
                            .group(countryValue)
                            .colors(d3.scale.category10())
                            .colorDomain([0, 3])
                            .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? geoChart.colors()(d) : '#ccc'; })
                            .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", function (d) {
                                return d.properties.name;
                            }),

                    dc.bubbleOverlay("#us-chart")
                            .svg(d3.select("#us-chart svg"))
                            .dimension(countries)
                            .group(countryValue)
                            .radiusValueAccessor(function(p) {
                                //console.log(p);
                                return p.val;
                            })
                            .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4]))
                            .point("Angola",200,200)


                ])


            dc.renderAll();
```

I have a sneaky feeling compositeChart will only work with charts based on a grid system, like line and bar charts. Is this right? In which case, is there a way to add a bubbleOverlay to a choropleth in DC, without doing it manually?

Comment: You're right about the Composite - it's derived from / only works with Coordinate Grid charts. It's dangerous but you could try to assign one chart to the same svg element as the other using [.svg()](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+svg). If the css selectors are independent the two charts may be able to ignore each other. No guarantees though!